# jQuery add class to xlink:href

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

```
$('a[xlink:href=#'+value.id+']').addClass("foo");
```

I have an svg which has `<a xlink:href="#21" xlink:title="21"></a>` arround the polygons.

What I'm trying to do is add a class to the `a` where the `xlink:href` matches that of `value.id`

Comment: and... what's happening ? Are you getting an error ? Please be more explicit and provide more information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to escpae the meta characters before using them as selectors by double backslash.

Do this:

```
$('a[xlink\\:href=#'+value.id+']').addClass("foo");
```

jQuery doc says:

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~` ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with
>   id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\.bar").

Comment: Thanks for getting the selector sorted. I have to use `.attr('class','foo');` in order to get the class added

Comment: Yes, very annoying not being able to use addClass when dealing with multiple classes but using attr suffices.